# POST entity with a byte array attribute as JSON

Tags: jersey-2.0

I'm new with REST and have to make a POST that receive an entity with a nested object that has inside a byte array.
This is my POST:

```
@POST
@Path("/post-entity")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response processEventcallback(ProcessEvent processEvent) {

    System.out.println(entity.toString());
    return null;
}
```

I call the POST like this:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Entity entity = new Entity ();
    entity .setId("645");
    entity .setKey("cqp");
    entity .setVersion("1.0");

    Message msg= new Message();
    msg.setContent(Base64.getEncoder().encode("post test".getBytes()));
    msg.setId("carl");
    entity.setMsg(msg);

    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/myRest/webapi/");

    Response response = target.path("send" ).request()
            .post(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

When i use xml as media type in the post it's all ok, the problem is when i use (json as in the code before), i get:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart
```

if I remove the byte array in message it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

ok, I hope to be more tired than stupid...but as the 
"Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart" suggest, by adding javax.mail to the dependencies all is solved...